# How to re-enable 'Tell Me What to do ' bar in MS Office Apps

Tags: microsoft-office

I am running Office Apps 2021 MSO (Version 2202 Build 16.0.14931.20128) 64-bit.

Recently I noticed that on all my office apps, I don't have the light bulb ('Tell me what you want to do' bar).

Can anyone tell me how to enable it or even a shortcut key.

Answer (score 0):

The To-Do bar is currently only available in Outlook.
I never used it, so I can't know if it was ever a general feature of Office,
but I don't remember ever seeing it in Word.

The Microsoft article
[Use and customize the To-Do bar](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-and-customize-the-to-do-bar-4b6c5bb4-88a0-46c2-9159-6d0a0133ff79?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)
describes using it. It is found in the View pane, Layout group:

[image]

If this is missing for some reason, you could
Restore/Reset the Folder View settings in Outlook.
This is found in the View pane, Current View group,
button Reset View.